# Convert Equals (=) to separated value to key and pair in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I have data coming like this

```
1 = Answer1<br />
2 = Answer2<br />
3 = Answer3<br />
4 = Answer4<br />
5 = Answer5<br />
6 = Answer6<br />
7 = Answer7<br />
8 = Answer8<br />
9 = Answer9<br />
10 = Answer10<br />
11 = Answer11<br />
12 = Answer12<br />
13 = Answer13<br />
14 = Answer14<br />
15 = Answer15<br />
16 = Answer16<br />
17 = Answer17<br />
18 = Answer18<br />
19 = Answer19<br />
20 = Answer20<br />
21 = Answer21<br />
22 = Answer22<br />
23 = Answer23<br />
24 = Answer24<br />
25-26 = Answer25,Answer26<br />
27 = Answer27<br />
28-29 = Answer28,Answer29
```

The above is the value of variable $lines. Since the answer can come in array, I got 27 key while using explode like `$lines = explode( "\r\n", $lines );`.

The expected answer of mine would be array that has number before `=` and value after `=`, and if the answer is comma separated, I would like it to be like following,

`28-29 => array('Answer28', 'Answer29');`

How can I achieve that using PHP?

Comment: Explode each line by `=` then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `explode()` on each line using `foreach()`

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

```php
$lines = explode("<br />\r\n", $lines);

$result = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    [$k, $v] = explode(" = ", $line);
    $result[$k] = explode(",", $v);
}

print_r($result);
```